# what's the function of ungroup() under below R code

Tags: r, dplyr

I am really new to R, and I am trying to pick it up myself. I got a code online and not really understand why there is **ungroup()** in the code below. To my understanding, there is no aggregate function, why we need to ungroup??

```
a<- a%>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(b= sum(c, d, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(e= b* x)
```

Comment: It removes the effect of `rowwise()`.  Details are given in the online documentation.  Even with no aggregation, the effects of `rowwise()` persist.  Compare the outputs from `print(a)` with and without the call to `rowwise()` in the construction of `a`.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: As @Limey mentioned, the definition of `rowwise` is **Group** input by rows

Comment: Since you're learning R,  it might be helpful to make another object (`temp`), where you remove the `rowwise()` grouping, and see how it changes the result: `temp <- a %>% mutate(b= sum(c, d, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you guys so much!!!!!!!!!!